# replace some character from string (url)

Tags: javascript

I tried to remove some character from a string, but it failed and I don't know why.

This is the code

```
path='url("https://www.example.com/folder/next/another/myfilename.jpg")';

var file = path.split('/'); 
console.log('file is: '+file);
file = file[file.length-1];
console.log('file is: '+file);
file=file.replace('/[")(]/g',''); // try also replace('/[")(]','') failed
console.log('file is: '+file);
return file;
```

In the console I read

```
file is: url("https:,,www.example.com,folder,next,another,myfilename.jpg")
file is: myfilename.jpg")
file is: myfilename.jpg")
```

I don't understand why the "() charachters by the replace function won't replaced.

Thanks for helping and explaining!

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: path is not defined` What is `path`?

Comment: maybe make `'/[")(]/g'` a regular expression, not a string by remove the quotes `file.replace(/[")(]/g,'')`

Comment: Which characters do you want to remove?

Comment: @ CertainPerformance you've right, ive update the post
@ Jack Bashford at the end i want to have only the filename, so i must remove the path and the url("")

Comment: What do you want from the path string? Is "myfilename.jpg" what you'd like to have as a result?

Comment: So, just to confirm, you only want `my filename.jpg`? What exact string would you like as output?

Comment: just replace whats left file.replace('")','');

Comment: try this : var file = path.split('"')
console.log(file[1].split('/')[file[1].split('/').length -1])

Comment: yes i only need the filename with extension filename.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove quotes in your regex:

```
function testFunction() {
    path='url("https://www.example.com/folder/next/another/myfilename.jpg")';

    var file = path.split('/'); 
    console.log('file is: '+file);
    file = file[file.length-1];
    console.log('file is: '+file);
    file=file.replace(/[")(]*/g, ''); 
    console.log('file is: '+file);
    return file;   
}
testFunction();
```

In console:

```
file is: url("https:,,www.example.com,folder,next,another,myfilename.jpg")
file is: myfilename.jpg")
file is: myfilename.jpg
```

Return value is `"myfilename.jpg"` now.
Is it what youwhant?

Comment: yes, that was the problem, i was in faith, that the regex must be in quotes

Comment: Yeah.. right..i also find the issue.. But @mikeD u can use better approach for this problem.
Something like path.split('/').pop().split('"')[0]; or path.split('"') console.log(file[1].split('/')[file[1].split('/').length -1])  or so on and so fourth...

Answer (score 1):

Correct regex to use here would be `/[()"]*/g` instead of `'/[")(]/g'`

Comment: file=file.replace('/[()"]*/g',''); brings me the same result like in my post

Comment: Notice quotes around the regex. Hope you have already got that.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const path = 'url("https://www.example.com/folder/next/another/myfilename.jpg")';

const filename = path.split('/').pop().split('"')[0];
console.log(filename);
```

## Method

1. Split your string based on `/`
2. Get the last item with `pop`. This will give you `myfilename.jpg")`
3. Split again with `"`
4. Get the first item with `array[0]`. This will give you `myfilename.jpg`

## Functions

- **Use [Array.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)** to split your string based on a delimiter. The first time it's the `/`, the second time it's the `"` character
- **Use [Array.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)** to get (and remove) the last item in an array